# How to set some value in express backend server.js file and use it in create-react-app code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

I have a simple create-react-app with a express backend with only 1 file (server.js) whose job is to just execute build folder and start the web app.

> server.js code looks like below:

```
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'prod'
const port = process.env.PORT ? process.env.PORT : 3000
const app = express()
var env = ""

// check below environment variable to identify on what environment on cloud service web-application is running
process.env.ENVIRONMENT_NAME === 'dev' ? env = 'dev' : env = 'prod'

// Add expressjs 'logger' plugin for printing logs and FE errors
app.use(
    logger({
        noop: isProduction
    })
)

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    // if i try to log env name like below i'm able to see the value
    // but if i try to log this anywhere like below in react code (it's always undefined)
    console.log(process.env.ENVIRONMENT_NAME);
})


// Serves static assets
app.use(express.static('./build'))
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './build', 'index.html'))
})

app.listen(port, (error, result) => {
    if (!isProduction && error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    console.log('Server running on port ' + port)
})
```

Below is how my react app starts?

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "npm run build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=prod node server.js",
    "develop": "react-scripts start"
  },
```

What I'm trying to achieve now?

1.) My create-react-app is having some components like drop-downs, radio-buttons etc and based upon some selections fetch rest-api calls are done in react code app.js etc and accordingly data came in the response is loaded on the page.

2.) Now, there are two rest-api end-points. One is dev and one is prod.
For eg: `www.example-dev.com/ , www.example-prod.com/`.

3.) So, based upon what cloud environment is determined in server.js code using `process.env.ENVIRONMENT_NAME === 'dev' ? env = 'dev' : env = 'prod'` on which my create-react-app is running, i want to call respective rest-api end point like `www.example-{env}.com/`

4.) So, i want to know the right way to set this value in `server.js` and use it in the react-app some component class wherever i want.

For eg:

Below is some react component piece of code, where i want to use env value set in server.js:

```
 handleOnChange = async selectedObj => {

      let responseObj = await callRestAPI(`www.example-${env}.com`);
      this.props.onChange(selectedObj);
  };
```

Please help.

Comment: Using custom environment variables: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables

Comment: my variable doesnt start with "REACT_APP_" If you can give me a example, it will be helpful.

Comment: That's the way it works: "_Note: You must create custom environment variables beginning with REACT_APP. Any other variables except NODE_ENV will be ignored_"

Comment: My requirement is very close to this example-> https://gist.github.com/hoolymama/99a65d22334a15e1235e5687c6b23c38#file-server-js

Comment: only thing is in the above example, they have /config get method end-point. I dont have anything like that. I just want to set the values like in this example in var config declaration and use it in entire app. Makes sense?

Comment: Well now you know the two ways of doing this. So pick one. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, here are few different ways

1. Using create react app docs REACT_APP thing
2. Use a templating engine for index.html
3. have endpoint as /config
4. create a js file dynamically, include it in your index.html

1 to 3 ways you can find doc online

for 4th way here is how you can do

```
fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './build', 'config.js'), `window.SERVER_DATA = { env : ${process.env.ENVIRONMENT_NAME}}`);
```

Make sure you do this before express.static

With your code above, here is how it looks

```
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'prod'
const port = process.env.PORT ? process.env.PORT : 3000
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');
var env = ""

// check below environment variable to identify on what environment on cloud service web-application is running
process.env.ENVIRONMENT_NAME === 'dev' ? env = 'dev' : env = 'prod'

// Add expressjs 'logger' plugin for printing logs and FE errors
app.use(
    logger({
        noop: isProduction
    })
)

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    // if i try to log env name like below i'm able to see the value
    // but if i try to log this anywhere like below in react code (it's always undefined)
    console.log(process.env.ENVIRONMENT_NAME);
})



fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './build', 'config.js'), `window.SERVER_DATA = { env : "${process.env.ENVIRONMENT_NAME}"}`);

// Serves static assets
app.use(express.static('./build'))
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './build', 'index.html'))
})

app.listen(port, (error, result) => {
    if (!isProduction && error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    console.log('Server running on port ' + port)
})
```

update your index.html to use our new js file

```
<script src="./config.js"></script>
```

in your react component, you can access by

```
console.log(window.SERVER_DATA)
```

working example:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/express-5o8ei

Comment: can u create a short example of above?

Comment: steps 1-4 are steps of one single method right? or you are pointing to multiple ways to do it from 1-3?

Comment: I have to do something like this : https://gist.github.com/hoolymama/99a65d22334a15e1235e5687c6b23c38#file-server-js (they have set up the variable in config var, at the top of server.js). but they have config end point, meaning when they call example.com/config, then only they will have access to those variable as they will get in the response. But i dont want additional end point

Comment: maybe i didnt understand properly. An example or link to an example will be really helpful

Comment: I added example above, does that make sense ?

Comment: let me give it a try, i will let you know in few mins.

Comment: is it needs to be accessed by window.SERVER_DATA.env in react component?

Comment: yes exactly window.SERVER_DATA.env.

you can modify that if you want to

Comment: After you run your app, check your build folder. it should have file called config.js, open it it should have window.SERVER_DATA = { env : data}

Comment: Here is the full working code https://codesandbox.io/embed/express-5o8ei

Comment: works perfectly now. Catch was quotes in config on env and dev were missing

Answer (score 0):

You can provide an environment variable that starts with `REACT_APP_` for example `REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT_NAME`

And in your react code you can access it like this:

```
let env = process.env.REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT_NAME;    
let responseObj = await callRestAPI(`www.example-${env}.com`);
```

You can also update the build script to pass the variable like this

```
"build": "REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT_NAME=$ENVIRONMENT_NAME react-scripts build",
```

Comment: my env variable is coming from somewhere else, and i can't add "REACT_APP_" infront of it

Comment: makes sense now clearly. But, in this build scripts, i have to write $process.env. ENVIRONMENT_NAME or just $ENVIRONMENT_NAME?

Comment: just $ENVIRONMENT_NAME

Comment: it's not working for me. This is what i did -> updated build script in package.json with "build": "REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT_NAME=$ENVIRONMENT_NAME react-scripts build" and tried to use in react-app as let env = process.env.REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT_NAME;    
let responseObj = await callRestAPI(`www.example-${env}.com`); When i try to log it, its value is undefined

Comment: how do you run your app? what's the environment, cloud?

Comment: In cloud, it first executes postinstall script which executes build scripts and after that start script is executed which starts node server (server.js) which renders all the files in build folder